# Pass to WCF string and parse it with JSON Newton

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, wcf, wcf-binding

I have

```
var sendThisString = JSON.stringify({ 'value': jsObj });
```

and I have WCF

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
 public string RowString(string rawJSON)
 {
        return "";
 }
```

So I did not want to use standard WCF serialisation my json string to C# object

I need to pass json string to WCF and then I will parse it by my serialisation

I just want  to see sample (client and server side) where you pass to WCF string "{'test':'test1'}" or another

Comment: What do you mean it fails if jsObj is "big".  What error are you getting when your sending WCF a big string ?

Comment: How **BIG** does jsObj have to be until you see a problem?? Default message size for WCF messages is 64K - any chance you get into trouble when you hit that size ??

Comment: i just need i simple sample where you pass your json as string to wcf and it will not automatically deserialise to c# object

Comment: If you don't need WCF desirialization, maybe you don't need WCF at all? Consider HTTP Handlers or WCF Web API (http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP) as analog.

Comment: thanks i will look to this solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decide replace jsObj with string, or do not use wcf

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use WCF to receive raw JSON (or any RAW data, for that matter), you can use the raw programming model - take a `Stream` as the input parameter. More information at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-receiving-arbitrary-data.aspx.